# identify this tall grass plant?

Tags: identification, grass

I bought this guy shortly before Hurricane Sandy, and then was stranded away from my apartment for a couple weeks while it died. It's managing to come back to life, but I'd love to know what kind of grass this is so I can best take care of it. Any guesses?

[image: grass]

Comment: Im not sure what type of plant that is but the first thing you should do is take off al of the old dead grass so the plant can breathe and grow to its full potential.

Comment: I'll do that, but out of curiosity, how does the dead grass prevent new grass from breathing?

Comment: sunlight and the dead roots take up space inside to pot that the living grass could use to grow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it — it's Gracillimus Maiden Grass ([*Miscanthus sinensis "Gracillimus"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscanthus_sinensis))